# How to replace a class with id using python BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML content, in which need to replace the class of these two divs to id and wrap them up in a wrapper div with another id using beautifulsoup4.

Input:

```
<div class="section1">section one content</div>
<div class="section2">section two content</div>
```

output:

```
<div id="section-wrapper">
<div id="section1">section one content</div><div id="section2">section two content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML tags were not displayed - probably that triggered the close votes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that. One approach would involve using [`.new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) and resetting the `.attrs` value of every section:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
    <div class="section1">section one content</div>
    <div class="section2">section two content</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

wrapper = soup.new_tag("div", {"id": "section-wrapper"})
for section in soup.select("[class^=section]"):
    section.attrs = {"id": section["class"]}

    wrapper.append(section)

print(wrapper.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div>
 <div id="section1">
  section one content
 </div>
 <div id="section2">
  section two content
 </div>
</div>
```